# Random freezes on MBP9,2 + Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mac, macbook, macbook-pro

I have a MBP9,2 (mid-2012) at work. I put Ubuntu 12.04 on it after some efforts. Everything works more or less now, except I get random freezing every now and then. I have to power off the machine to restore it. Wondering if anyone had the similar issue.

My setup:

- MacBook Pro 9,2 (mid 2012)
- Ubuntu 12.04 (installed using the special image for Macs)
- No proprietary drivers
- xmonad on Unity 2D

So far the freezes look to be sporadic and spontaneous.

Answer (score 0):

First, install the proprietary graphics drivers.

Next check your fans and make sure there clear and running smooth. Linux uses a different profile for the fans, and it can cause problems if the fans are clogged or dirty (they turn up at a warmer temp).

Also your going to need the wireless proprietary drivers. [Take a look here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro9-2/Quantal) for full instructions (they should work for 12.04.

You might also consider upgrading to 12.10 it seems to have much better support for the MBP  9.2

[Ubuntu 12.10](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro9-2/Quantal)
[Ubuntu 12.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro9-2/Precise)

12.04 has more "manual installs".

Also make sure your booting in BIOS mode. This can be pretty tricky if your not using refit. You might also try resetting your PRAM and NVRAM. It shouldn't make a difference, but sometimes it does.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The model I have has Intel integrated graphics, so there's no proprietary video driver to install. I did have wireless card driver installed and configured. I'm also using refit. I'd go on Ubuntu 12.10 but they discontinued unity 2d, which I rely on to run xmonad. (I know I don't have to, but I don't like using the bare x11)